# Use fabric (Crashlytics and Twitter) android

Tags: android, twitter, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I use method loggin with button Twitter, but recently I included crashlytics, crashlytics work good in my app except in the screen login, the logcat show the message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start Twitter Kit with Fabric.with() first

and crash my app, how resolve this problem?,  is the only screen with the error

Answer (score 0):

In order to start the Fabric instance, first

1. Create a class called MyApplication which extends the Application class
2. call Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); inside onCreate

public class MyApplication extends Application {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

}
```

}

3. In your manifest file's application file, do the following

Comment: Thanks I found the error, my case is that I have 2 screen before (splashcreen and tutorial) where I implement only crashlytics, this affect the function of Twitter kit, you should never start the crashlytics before twitter kit, if you have a splash screen   and tutorial is not necessary report to crashlytics